# How to send email from jenkins using port number 25

Tags: jenkins, gmail

How to send email from jenkins using port number 25.

Jenkins release version 2.235.3 SMTP port field for Extended E-mail Notification keeps getting reverted back to port no. 25  even after adding either 465 or 587 port number in that field and clicking "Apply and Save" buttons.

i have used telnet to verify whether smtp.gmail.com is accessible/open on ports 25,465 & 587.
smtp.gmail.com is accessible and open on 465 and 587, but not on port 25 & telnet gives me below message.

"telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable"

how can we use port number 25 of smtp to send mails  using jenkins or general.

Is it even advisable to use port no. 25 of gmail to send emails from third party vendors.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow status of this issue from link here https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-63367

On 08/14/2020 they will be releasing a fix for it but if you do not want to wait for it you can downgrade email-ext-plugin to 2.71 and you will be able to change SMTP port number. This is an issue everyone is facing for version 2.73 and 2.74. Hope it will be fixed with 2.74 version.

If you just setup your Jenkins, you will not have an option to downgrade, instead:

1. uninstall plugin and then navigate to https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/email-ext/ and download version 2.71
2. Go to Jenkins > Manage Jenkins> Manage Plugins > Advanced > Upload Plugin  and choose downloaded verion and click on upload.

Let it finish installing and after that, restart your Jenkins. Now you should be able to change SMTP port without any issue!